# How to rotate something using spritekit relative to user touch coordinates

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I want to rotate a gun based on the user dragging their finger on the screen. I figure i will need my cartesian points in polar coordinates and that i will need a long press gesture which is both things that i have. I am just wondering how i would go about programming this? sorry i'm really new to sprite kit i have read all of apple's documentation and i'm having a hard time finding this. My anchor point is 0,0.

```
-(void)shootBullets:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *) gestureRecognizer
{
    double radius;
    double angle;
      SKSpriteNode *gun = [self newGun];
 }
```

i figured out how to get the angle but now my zrotation wont work. Like i nslog and the angles are right but when i click gun.zrotation and i tap nothing happens? please help i'm getting uber mad.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
SKSpriteNode *gun = [self newGun];
self.gunRotation = atanf(location.y/location.x)/0.0174532925;
gun.zRotation = self.gunRotation;
NSLog(@"%f",gun.zRotation);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very old question, but here is what I did - hopefully it will help someone out there:

```
#import "MyScene.h"
#define SK_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(__ANGLE__) ((__ANGLE__) * 0.01745329252f) // PI / 180
```

Then add this:

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint positionInScene = [touch locationInNode:self];

        float deltaX = positionInScene.x - gun.position.x;
        float deltaY = positionInScene.y - gun.position.y;

        float angle = atan2f(deltaY, deltaX);

        gun.zRotation = angle - SK_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(90.0f);  
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know this language, this answer showed up in "Late Answers". Is there supposed to be an f in this? `* 0.01745329252f`

Comment: `SK_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(90.0f)` is actually `M_PI_2`.

Comment: There is a built-in function for degrees and radians: [`GLKMathDegreesToRadians()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GLkit/Reference/GLKMathUtils/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/GLKMathDegreesToRadians).

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [answers I got to this question about how to implement a rotary knob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621141/iphone-ipad-circular-intensity-gauge-control-image-included), people have already figured out all the geometry, all you need to do is implement a transparent rotary knob, get its angle and pass it to your sprite kit object, using action rotate